# Вопрос по Domain Layer в архитектуре MVVM (или CleanArchitecture?)

Tags: android, mvvm, шаблоны-проектирования

Всем привет! Имеются такие вопросы:

1. Domain layer относится к MVVM, или к CleanArchitecture ?
2. Domain Layer - это что-то наподобие presenter'a, в который в качестве view-интерфейса кладётся viewModel? Или это совсем другое? (если да, то прошу пожалуйста объяснить, что)

Answer (score 0):

Если говорить условно и коротко, то Clean Architecture обычно делится на три слоя: Presentation (слой представления или UI слой), Domain (слой бизнес логики) и Data (слой данных)

Так вот, все архитектуры вида MV* относятся к Presentation слою.
В Domain слое обычно располагают логику взаимодействия между Presentation и Data слоем. Там располагаются такие сущности как Interactor или UseCase, которые запрашивают данные из Data слоя и передают/преобразуют их для Presentation слоя.

Можно почитать вот [эту статью](https://habr.com/ru/post/250659/) для ознакомления.
А [тут](https://www.fandroid.info/lektsiya-4-po-arhitekture-android-prilozheniya-clean-arcitecture/) помимо теории есть ещё некоторые примеры.

Comment: @Cypher ViewModel это Presentation слой, в Domain как и сказали Interactor'ы, UseCase'ы, Entity

Comment: @Cypher Не могли бы вы указать источник, где ViewModel относят к Domain слою.